# How to prevent Fish shell from closing when typing Ctrl-D (EOF)

Tags: shell, unix, fish

I am using fish shell. When I type Ctrl-D, it sends a EOF to my terminal and then terminal closes.

I want to make it such that ctrl-D does not close my iterm2.

I saw that people have set up IGNOREEOF in bash shell like this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27588/how-can-i-keep-controld-from-disconnecting-my-session

However, I don't think this variable exists in fish. Does anybody know how I can force iterm2(with default fish shell) to not close on ctrl-D?

Comment: This is treated on the shell level, so it has nothing to do with iTerm2.

Comment: (Alternatively, you can map `^D` to send something else in iTerm2, including "Ignore", but I don't think that's a good idea. To limit the effect to fish, have a dedicated profile called "fish" or something, then use iTerm2's automatic profile switching.)

Comment: You are right, sir.  That could be one option. I just cant help but wonder whether there is any fish expert out there who also use iterm2, what they use to prevent this from happening :)

Comment: Not true that it has *nothing* to do with the terminal.  Some terminals can be set to not close the tab/window on program exit.

Comment: @GringoSuave all discussions and answers related specifically to fish, and provide no value for non-fish iTerm2 users.  Unfortunately, search engines and SO itself think this is the best page to answer "how to prevent ctrl d from closing iterm", but these answers are useless to most of us.

Comment: For those who come seeking an answer to this question and are using zsh or bash, see this: https://superuser.com/questions/1243138/why-does-ignoreeof-not-work-in-zsh

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the default key binding for control-D:

```
bind \cd delete-or-exit
```

you can find this by just running `bind`.

(`delete-or-exit` is just a function, which you can read with `functions delete-or-exit`.)

So it's exiting because that's what the default behavior is. You can make control-D do something else. For example, maybe it should delete the character under the cursor:

```
bind \cd delete-char
```

If you want to make this permanent, add it to your `fish_user_key_bindings` function:

1. Run `funced fish_user_key_bindings` which starts editing
2. Put `bind \cd delete-char` within the function
3. Hit return to create the function
4. Run `funcsave fish_user_key_bindings` to save it

Comment: You can also run `bind \cd` to get the binding for just that.

Comment: Nice, I created a  function similar to  delete-or-exit and bind it to \cd, now, C-d will not exit but execute another command I always use.

Answer (score 2):

### Shell approach

After reading this question and answer I updated my delete-or-exit function to ask for confirmation rather than completely deactivate it:

```
cd ~/.config/fish/functions/
cp /usr/share/fish/functions/delete-or-exit.fish .
```

Then edit/replace:

```
function delete-or-exit

    set -l cmd (commandline)

    switch "$cmd"
        case ''
            read --nchars 1 --local -P 'Do you want to exit? [y/N] ' confirm
            switch $confirm
                case Y y
                    exit 0
                case '' N n
                    echo -n (fish_prompt)
            end

        case '*'
            commandline -f delete-char
    end
end
```

It has a minor issue in that it displays the prompt twice when you finish, but it seems better than no times if you don't print it (see N case above).  Perhaps someone has a solution to that.

### Terminal approach

iTerm and many other terminals have a setting says something like, "keep terminal open when program exits."

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning a different action to `Ctrl+d` you could also unbind it through `bind --erase --preset \cd`. With all steps:

- Run `funced fish_user_key_bindings` which starts editing
- Put `bind --erase --preset \cd` within the function
- Hit return to create the function
- Run `funcsave fish_user_key_bindings` to save it