# How to reset fish-shell key bindings

Tags: key-bindings, fish

I messed up my fish-shell key bindings and now get this on new shell:

```
fish: The function call stack limit has been exceeded. Do you have an accidental infinite loop?
    and __original_fish_user_key_bindings
        ^
in function '__original_fish_user_key_bindings'
    called on standard input

in function '__original_fish_user_key_bindings'
    called on standard input
```

How do I reset my key-bindings and get past this error?

(I was trying to follow instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34216850/how-to-prevent-iterm2-from-closing-when-typing-ctrl-d-eof/34218767) & messed up something)

Comment: Try looking in  `~/.config/fish/functions/` for functions that appear related to key bindings, and deleting or moving them.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove
`~/.local/share/omf` and `~/.config/fish/conf.d/omf.fish` files to silence error message of fish startup

Or
Open ~/.local/share/omf/init.fish file and comment these lines

> ## functions -q __original_fish_user_key_bindings
>
> ## and __original_fish_user_key_bindings